# Human-readable hard-coding dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, format, human-readable

Assume that I wish to hard-coding a data frame in R.

```
my_df = data.frame(list(Name=c("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"), 
              Result=c("Hello", NA, "foobar", "World")))
```

If the data frame was a lot longer (e.g., if it were to comprise dozens of rows), it would not be immediately intuitive that `baz` is associated with `foobar` (i.e., that these two values share the same row).

Is there a visually more human-readable way of hard-coding a data frame in R?

**EDIT 1:**

To clarify my question, I am not looking for an alternative way to format the hard-coding of the data frame (such as aligning the two rows by spacing out the words with whitespaces). Instead, what I am looking for is a way to, for example, specify the data frame rowwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `frame_data()` command from the `tibble` package.

For example:

```
dat <- frame_data(
  ~x, ~y,  ~z,
  "a", 2,  3.6,
  "b", 1,  8.5
)
```

It provides a hardcoding that is more 'by row' than the default data.frame entry method which is 'by column'.

[Source](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to use `read.table(text = "...")`, e.g.

```
d <- read.table(text = "Name Result
                        foo  Hello
                        bar  NA
                        baz  foobar
                        qux  World", 
                header = TRUE, 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(d)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Name  : chr  "foo" "bar" "baz" "qux"
#  $ Result: chr  "Hello" NA "foobar" "World"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this from a [tweet by Noam Ross](https://twitter.com/noamross/status/665212230581948417):

```
 readr::read_delim(
   '  Name  |   Result
    # -------------------
       foo  |   Hello
       bar  |   NA
       baz  |   foobar
       qux  |   World ',
   trim_ws = TRUE, comment="#", delim="|")
```